# Binding key for Apple Documentation opening

Tags: xcode, binding, xcode5

Is there way to bind some Key to open Apple Documentation(like u open it with from Utilities/Class Reference) in Xcode ? 
I know you can Cmd+left to jump to definition.

"NSString" - open documentation for NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option + Double-Click works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Help menu. You'll see Xcode already has a keyboard shortcut to open the documentation window, Cmd-Shift-0. If you want a different key combination to open the documentation window, use Xcode's Key Bindings preferences.

Comment: Sure, I know that. I meant: Open documentation with click on some class, like "NSString" - open documentation for NSString. It doesn't look hard, because there is a reference to class in utilities and cmd+leftclick opening definition. Thanks